# WooCommerce Delete all products from cart and add current product to cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to WooCommerce and I need to be able to only add one single product in the cart. I want to clear all products and add the current product to the cart when I click the "Add to cart" button.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this,

```
//For removing all the items from the cart
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id,$qty);
```

class file is `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/classes/class-wc-cart.php`

Hope its helps..

Comment: Hey, where should i put this in class-wc-cart.php?

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying the plugin files directly. They'll be overwritten whenever the user updates.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee You don't need to modify core file I just added it for reference , you can add the global in your functions.php then do the task with an ajax call.

Answer (score 24):

I have got an exact solution for this. 
Try following code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'wdm_empty_cart', 10,  3);

function wdm_empty_cart( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) 
{

    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

    // Do nothing with the data and return
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

The above filter is defined in class-wc-cart.php within function add_to_cart(). 
http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#774-905 
Thus, when add to cart button is pressed, it empties the cart and then add the product.

Comment: Would it be helpful to lower the priority a bit, so that our filter to empty cart is run before anything else?

Comment: I tried so many things to fix this problem and this was the one that worked. Thank you, works perfectly now.