# Empty cart before add to cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I am using WP Job manager with Woo Subscriptions.

Now:

1. Initially, I selected a package(Woo Subscription)
2. Then I added all the details.
3. But did not submit it.
4. Came back to the site, so to buy again I need to select a package. So I selected the package and filled in details and went to the payment package.
5. Now in my cart both the packages are present (i.e the one I selected without buying first time and the recent one)
6. How can this be fixed so the latest selected one is in the cart and earlier one deleted as soon as latest one selected.

I tried this [Woocommerce Delete all products from cart and add current product to cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181911/woocommerce-delete-all-products-from-cart-and-add-current-product-to-cart)  but did not help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Updated *(with 2 different alternatives)*:

You should try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart', 20, 3 );
function remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    return $passed;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme)*. **Tested and works** with both ajax-add-to-cart and normal add-to-cart…

---

Or you can use this different one that will keep in cart the last added item:

```
// Keep only last cart item
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'keep_only_last_cart_item', 30, 1 );
function keep_only_last_cart_item( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    $cart_items = $cart->get_cart();

    if( count( $cart_items ) > 1 ){
        $cart_item_keys = array_keys( $cart_items );
        $cart->remove_cart_item( reset($cart_item_keys) );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme)*. **Tested and works**

Comment: Thanks for your quick response buddy, I added this filter i functions.php, it did not work. The package gets selected using "Ajax" I am not sure if that's causing the problem. 
-Select Package-->AddPosting->CheckOut page is the flow.

Comment: @Ram This code is tested and perfectly works with add to cart ajax and normal add to cart. The hook that I use is located either in normal `WC_Cart` `add_to_cart()` method and in `WC_Ajax` `add_to_cart()` method too… Is not possible for anybody to reproduce your issue, your settings, your installation and plugins…

Comment: @Ram I have added another different hooked function that could work for your case… Please try it and let me know if it works… Thanks.

Comment: I am unsure why first one did not work. But the second filter you shared worked like a charm. Thanks LoicTheAztec

Comment: @ LoicTheAztec I have already up voted the answer, thanks again.

Comment: Still works, but are these filter functions safe to use long term? How likely that a Woo or WordPress update will break this eventually?

Comment: This is about WooCommerce and this WooCommerce hooks will remain in future, no worry…

Answer (score -1):

Go to your site database and look for table 'wp_woocommerce_sessions' and see if its 'session_id' column contains 0 value if so

1. delete all these 0 entry records
2. make 'session_id' Column as primary.
3. make 'session_id' Column auto increment.

Comment: Bad idea. You don't always want to lose all session variables when emptying the cart.

Comment: its not to delete session values  just to remove faulty records and correct the database structure