Empty Woocommerce Ajax Cart before adding multiple items via url to cart
I am using the following code to allow adding multiple items via url (...com/checkout/?add-to-cart=632:11,422:7) to the woocommerce cart by calling the checkout page NOT cart page. Somehow it does not empty the logged in OR logged out users cart before adding the new items using WC()->cart->empty_cart();. Any idea why?
// Function to allow adding mulitple items via url in this format to checkout or cart ...com/checkout/?add-to-cart=632:11,422:7
function add_multiple_products_to_cart_9R_M2asdf() {
    // Ensure WooCommerce is installed and the 'add-to-cart' query parameter is present and formatted correctly.
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Form_Handler' ) || empty( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) || false === strpos( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'], ',' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Empty the cart before adding new items otherwise it just adds to the ones added before...
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    
    // Remove WooCommerce's default add_to_cart_action hook.
    remove_action( 'wp_loaded', array( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_action' ), 20 );

    // Split the product IDs and quantities.
    $product_entries = explode( ',', sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) );

    foreach ( $product_entries as $entry ) {
        // Split each entry into product ID and quantity.
        list($product_id, $quantity) = array_map('absint', explode( ':', $entry ) + [null, 1]);

        if ( ! $product_id ) {
            continue;
        }

        // Set the quantity in the request.
        $_REQUEST['quantity'] = $quantity;

        // Handle the final item using WooCommerce's default method.
        if ( end($product_entries) === $entry ) {
            $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] = $product_id;
            return WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action();
        }

        // Process the product.
        $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $product_id );
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if ( ! $product ) {
            continue;
        }

        $add_to_cart_handler = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', $product->get_type(), $product );

        // Handle different product types.
        if ( 'variable' === $add_to_cart_handler ) { // Variabl Products
            woo_invoke_private_method_93gK_M3q( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_handler_variable', $product_id );
        } elseif ( 'grouped' === $add_to_cart_handler ) { // Grouped Products
            woo_invoke_private_method_93gK_M3q( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_handler_grouped', $product_id );
        } elseif ( has_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler_' . $add_to_cart_handler ) ) { // Custom Handler
            do_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler_' . $add_to_cart_handler );
        } else { // simple product
            woo_invoke_private_method_93gK_M3q( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_handler_simple', $product_id );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'add_multiple_products_to_cart_9R_M2asdf', 15 );

/**
 * Invoke private method of a class.
 *
 * @param string $class_name
 * @param string $method_name
 * @param mixed  ...$args
 * @return mixed
 */
function woo_invoke_private_method_93gK_M3q( $class_name, $method_name, ...$args ) {
    if ( version_compare( phpversion(), '5.3', '<' ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'PHP version does not support ReflectionClass::setAccessible()', __LINE__ );
    }

    $reflection = new ReflectionClass( $class_name );
    $method = $reflection->getMethod( $method_name );
    $method->setAccessible( true );

    return $method->invoke( null, ...$args );
}


you should use the proper hooks that trigger add to cart like woocommerce_add_to_cart wp_loaded is too early i think

@Snuffy - this seems to work https://gist.github.com/kloon/4541017?permalink_comment_id=3081860#gistcomment-3081860 - now i can use checkout in my url instead of cart and got rid of the redirect from cart to checkout. If you add it as answer i would accept it - i cant add answers to my own questions due to my reputation.

Here is the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382193/empty-cart-before-add-to-cart-in-woocommerce
